# SharePoint 2013 CSS Reference Chart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'm after a SharePoint 2013 CSS Reference Chart.
    Anyone know of one.I have looked a bit but can't get to find one like the one for SP 2010.
    Any type of resources would be appreciated.

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 8):

Here are all the CSS reference charts I have encontered so far.

SharePoint 2007

http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm

SharePoint 2010

http://erikswenson.blogspot.se/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-base-css-classes.html

http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html

SharePoint 2013

http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-css-classes-that-suck-and-save-the-day/

Answer (score 8):

A few more resources:

Branding Global Nav

1. [Hiding Home Link in SP 2013 Top Nav](http://bemusedbi.blogspot.com/2013/04/hiding-home-link-in-sharepoint-2013-top.html)
2. http:// sharepoint.rackspace.com/branding-top-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013
3. http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/380/Branding-the-SharePoint-2013-Global-Navigation.aspx
4. [Customizing SP Global Navigation with CSS and Jquery](http://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/customizing-sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-part-3/)
5. https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Brand-SharePoint-Global-Navigation-Final-Part-7.aspx
6. http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-branding-101-cascading-style-sheets

Identifying Sharepoint CSS

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220046%28v=office.15%29.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn205275%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Additional

Users resources

1. [Useful CSS Classes in SharePoint 2013](https://joshmccarty.com/useful-css-classes-sharepoint-2013/)

We might be able to get it together!

Answer (score 4):

It's help you ?

[SharePoint 2013 Starter Stylesheet](http://sp2013stylesheet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That is an actual CSS file, no reference chart?

Answer (score -2):

Add a Script Block web part and then inside a style block

```
<style> @import url("http://www.yourco.com/siteassets/css/yourcssfile.css"); </style>
```