# Application page look like OOTB Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, application-pages, visual-studio-2013

I have created an application page (custom Page) in SharePoint. I want the application page to look like a SharePoint OOTB page. Is there any way to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use CSS classes which SharePoint use to render output. This classes will help you to give OOB look of SharePoint

This will help: [SharePoint 2013 CSS Reference Chart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89118/sharepoint-2013-css-reference-chart)

You can google for more information.

Comment: Can i do this using sharepoint controls?

Comment: I am not sure on that, but I guess for SharePoint controls also you will need to use CSS