# How to get a list of every css selector SP 2013 uses?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css

I am doing a cleanup of my previous sharepoint custom styling, and the developer has mixed custom styles with out of the box styles without properly labeling which is custom. I want to be able to distinguish between custom and out of the box css selectors. But I am not sure how. I looked at the core15.css but just because something is not there, doesn't mean that SharePoint is not using it. For example `.ms-WPBody` is used on web parts, but is not shown in the core15.css.

Does anyone know if there is a full list somewhere of out of the box styles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of these should help: [SharePoint 2013 CSS Reference Chart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89118/sharepoint-2013-css-reference-chart). Heather Solomon made a more complete chart for 2010 (https://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html), but seems to have only featured a subset for 2013: http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-css-classes-that-suck-and-save-the-day/